# How do you release a shared accelerator instance on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, accelerometer

I have created an accelerometer variable:

```
UIAccelerometer   *objAccelerometer;
```

that I am associating to the sharedAccelerometer instance:

```
objAccelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
objAccelerometer.delegate = self;
```

When I release this view (to load a different view), the accelerometer instance causes the program to die.  (If I have it commented out, I can switch between views without a problem).

I had a similar problem with an NSTimer, but once I called:

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

(prior to releasing and switching the views) everything worked fine.

How should I properly release the delegate or deallocate or release the accelerometer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't release the shared accelerometer - you never retained it (and shouldn't) - it's a singleton.

The accelerometer has a reference to *your* object. For it to release it just set it's delegate property to nil (because it's a property it will release its reference to your object).

Comment: That did it!  I thought there might be a function (like release or invalidate) -- but nil worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem. Read up on Objective C 2.0s property syntax to be sure you know what's going on here